# Работа с коллекциями Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

В проекте установлена связь у одного User может быть несколько девайсов (Один ко многим) Мне нужно получить один Device который принадлежит конкретному User, я уже могу получить все девайсы таким образом $user->devices, в данном случае я получаю коллекцию всех девайсов пользователя.

Но мне нужно получить девайс этого User у которого параметр в базе `os` = `Windows`

В sql запрос был бы таким:
SELECT * FROM `devices` WHERE `user_id` = `ID пользователя` and `os` = `Windows`;

Данная конструкция в моем случае почему-то возвращает null

```
$device = $user->devices->first(function ($request) {
        return 'os' === $request->os;
    });

 dd($device);
```

В $request->os содержится название ОС и оно там есть.

Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$user->devices()->where('os', 'Windows')->first()

Comment: Это же так элементарно, спасибо большое! Работает!

Comment: пожалуйста, отметь как решение)